# Deploying Laravel 5 on a server

Tags: php, laravel, server, synology

I am trying to deploy a larval project on my Sinology NAS so it could be available externally. Locally everything is working fine. However when i copy my project in my NAS, I simply get a 404 error.

Here is what I have checked:
1. Database connection.
2. Settings in `config/app.php`.
3. `php artisan route:list` is also working fine.

Yet, I am unable to get this to work. Any suggestions?

### Update:

By changing my `public/.htaccess` from: `Options -MultiViews` to `Options +Indexes` gives the home page, but no other re-direction works.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add "/public" after your address site, so like this: "www.example.com/public/...". Is it your problem?

Or you can change your laravel project to debug mode by change `debug` variable in `config/app.php` to `true`, so your laravel project can show the error message.

Answer (score 0):

After a few trials, finally got it to run on DS215j.

edit /etc/httpd/sites-enabled-user/httpd-vhost.conf-user

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName laravel.iw.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/services/web/laravel/public"
  ErrorDocument 403 "/webdefault/error.html"
  ErrorDocument 404 "/webdefault/error.html"
  ErrorDocument 500 "/webdefault/error.html"
</VirtualHost>
```

restart synology!

edit your local host
`192.168.1.xxx laravel.iw.com`